# How to return Server Sent Events using Asp.NET Web Api

Tags: asp.net, html

I want to be able to use server sent events with asp. Net Web api how do I do this

Comment: You start to use google and work though some examples and tutorials. Then, and only then, if there is still some question with a concrete piece of code, ask it here.

Answer (score 0):

SignalR is a nice library to send events from the web server to its clients. Have a look at http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr.

Comment: I checked it out, seems really great but my only problem is how do I connect to signalR because my client app is on another server and my backend is on another server, can you help or point me to any documentation